# How do I deserialize JSON in Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

I have an Xcode project which uses an NSURLConnection to make a request to a webservice, which returns JSON.

The JSON coming back looks like this:

```
{"d":"{\"Graphic\":{\"HAName\":\"HSName\",\"HALogo\":\"main_menu_top_logo.png\",\"BarColour\":-16744448,\"BarButtonTextColour\":-28444,\"TextColour\":-16744448,\"BackGroundColour\":-23296,\"Error\":\"\"},\"App\":{\"App1\":true,\"App1Title\":\"Application1\",\"App2\":true,\"App2Title\":\"Application2\"Error\":\"\"},\"Version\":25,\"Error\":\"\"}"}
```

I am trying to parse the JSON using:

```
NSDictionary* json = nil;
if (responseData) 
{
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
}
```

But when i look at the dictionary object, it looks like this:

```
d = "{\"Graphic\":{\"HAName\":\"HSName\",\"HALogo\":\"main_menu_top_logo.png\",\"BarColour\":-16744448,\"BarButtonTextColour\":-28444,\"TextColour\":-16744448,\"BackGroundColour\":-23296,\"Error\":\"\"},\"App\":{\"App1\":true,\"App1Title\":\"Application1\",\"App2\":true,\"App2Title\":\"Application2\"Error\":\"\"},\"Version\":25,\"Error\":\"\"};
```

The dictionary only contains 1 key / value pair.

How do i get the JSON object parsed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what the problem is, it's given you the top level dictionary which contains lots of other dictionaries.

What were you expecting if not this? You aren't going to get an array from this structure.

Comment: So i should be able to do something like [[json objectForKey:@"d"] objectForKey:@"Graphic"] to access the nested dictionary objects?

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest Or use `[json valueForKeyPath:@"d.Graphic"]` to access nested objects via dot notation.

Comment: valueForKeyPath throws this error:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x687a260> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Graphic.' What i dont understand is, in the JSON response, the "d" uses unescaped quotes, but the other quotes are unescaped. I suspect the JSON parser is not parsing the objects correctly. How do i unescape the rest of the quotes?

Comment: The response is a dictionary with a single value: another serialized JSON object (ie. a string itself containing JSON) stored under the key "d". You will need to grab the "d" value and deserialize that in turn.

Comment: Got to the bottom of the problem. Our WCF webservice was effectively serializing the JSON twice before sending it. Solution was found here: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/ - thanks for all the help and tips guys.